# storing AuthorizationCodeCredential in web app session

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, azure-identity

I am using the `azure-identity` library to authenticate users for accessing the Microsoft Graph API in my Spring Boot web application.

After getting the successfully getting the `code` via auth code grant redirect I want to store the access token and refresh token in the the web application session so that the user does not have to re-authenticate for doing multiple requests to the Microsoft Graph API.

How can I get hold of the tokens for storing them in the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this was to create a class that implements `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` that stores and loads the OAuth credentials in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The Authorization Code is a single-user code used to obtain an actual Access Token. You'll need to redeem that `code` for an `access_token` as described in [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redeem-a-code-for-an-access-token).

The response body that contains the `access_token` will also include a `refresh_token` value:

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4...",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctOD...",
}
```